# Can someone give me some quality sources (book, website, etc.) that help with combinatoric for competition math?

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, self-learning, education

Some combinatorial topics I have found to be useful in competitive math are

- Burnsides Lemma
- Stars and Bars
- Recursion
- Expected Value(Need help on this one)
- Extremal principle
- PIE
- Combinatoric Geometry
- Indicator functions with Sets
- Partially ordered sets(Erdős–Szekeres,Dilwort's,Mirsky's...)

If you are wondering what level I am looking for I am looking to be able to solve late AIME(around problems 10-15) combinatorics problems easily.

Comment: You might be interested in "Problem-Solving Methods in Combinatorics, an Approach to Olympiad Problems" by Pablo Soberon.